# MySQL - LOAD DATA INFILE with Line Number of file

Tags: mysql

How can I use LOAD DATA INFILE syntax with the Number Of line will be inserted too into a table..?
I used this query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/home/TAM/input/Upload/DOC20120919000000.csv' INTO TABLE tb_t_doc_d 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES (rrn_no, new_color_cd, new_main_dealer_cd, new_zone_cd, new_branch_cd, new_destination_cd, @var)
SET process_id = '1209219999999999', transaction_id = 'DC201209219999', reference = 
trim(TRAILING '\r' FROM @var), created_dt = sysdate(), created_by = "DIDIT", updated_dt = 
sysdate(), updated_by = "DIDIT", file_line_no = ???? ;
```

What should I filled in on `file_line_no = ????`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help:

```
set @row = 0;
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/home/TAM/input/Upload/DOC20120919000000.csv' INTO TABLE tb_t_doc_d 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES (rrn_no, new_color_cd, new_main_dealer_cd, new_zone_cd, new_branch_cd,       new_destination_cd, @var)
SET process_id = '1209219999999999', transaction_id = 'DC201209219999', reference = 
trim(TRAILING '\r' FROM @var), created_dt = sysdate(), created_by = "DIDIT", updated_dt = 
sysdate(), updated_by = "DIDIT", file_line_no = @row:=@row+1;
```

Comment: thanks, this is helpful! basically, `SET @row = 0; LOAD DATA ... SET file_line_no = @row:=@row+1;`

Comment: how can i show the value on file_line_no result of this?